# How do I enable editing the body of a block?

Tags: blocks

I have a block (in Drupal 7) with information in the body of it.

I want a specific user to be able to edit that information.

After assigning that user Administer blocks and Contextual links permissions the user can edit everything except the body and the following message shows:

[image]

Is there any way to enable the field for that user?

Comment: Maybe this field has text format, which hasn't permission for this user. Try to change text format to plain text and check one more time.

Comment: I have been trying to find the answer for so long and couldn't find anything wrong with it. Thank you changing the text format to plain text fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are facing this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1953434) because you probably created the block as a user who has access to a text format like *Full HTML* but the other user doesn't have that permission :( Here's what you can do:

- Sign in as the root user (uid 1) who created the block;
- Change the text format to *Basic HTML* or *Restricted HTML*.
- Go to *Admin > People > Permissions* page and make sure the other non-admin user has the permissions to use the text format you applied.
- Depending on your requirements, you can ignore point 2 and give *Full HTML* permissions to the concerned user.

Comment: By allowing the user to have full HTML permission I was able to do it. Thank you.